# On minimum value of $\sup \{x^2,\cos x\}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f=\sup\{x^2,\cos x\}$. Prove that the minimum of $f$ occurs at $x_0$ which is a solution to the equation $x^2=\cos x$.

I tried to use the fact that $$\max\{a,b\}=\dfrac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$$
so that the minimum can be proved to be:
$1$) It lies in $(-1,1)$ (range of $\cos x$ or otherwise $x^2$ dominates)
$2$) Note that the minimum as claimed happens when the modulus becomes zero$\ldots$

What Next?

Comment: $x^2$ and $\cos x$ are both even functions, so concentrate on $x\ge0$

Comment: Can you prove the second derivative of $x^2-\cos x$ is positive?  What does that mean?

Comment: But use of derivative is prohibited because this problem was in a chapter before derivative..,

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comment, we can focus on the positive part. The negative part would be by symmetry.

- $x^2$ is an increasing function for positive $x$.
- $\cos x$ is a decreasing function from $0$ to $\pi$.
- $\cos x$ is bigger than $x^2$ from $0$ to $x_0$.
- At $x_0$, we have $\cos x = x^2$.
- From $x=x_0$ to $\pi$, since $\cos x$ is decreasing and $x^2$ increases, we have $x^2 > \cos x$.
- For $x > \pi$, $x^2 > \pi^2 > 1 \ge \cos x$.

That is $$f(x) = \begin{cases}\cos x, & 0\le x \le x_0\\x^2, & x\ge x_0\end{cases}$$

Since $\cos x$ decreases from $0$ to $x_0$, we have $f(x) > f(x_0)$ for $0 \le x < x_0$.

Since $x^2$ increases from $x_0$ onwards, we have $f(x) > f(x_0)$ for $x> x_0$.

Hence the intersection position attains the minimum.